# Redirect from one location with wilcards using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I need help with how to use the htaccess when a folder and any subfolders get redirected to a new url.

Example: http:www.mysite.com/events/a-name-of-an-event  (the 'a-name-of-an-event' will vary)

to

http:www.mysite.com/fixtures/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RedirectMatch` directive in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/events/ /fixtures/
```

**OR using `mod_rewrite`:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^events/ /fixtures/ [L,R=301,NC]
```